# RESTful webservices : Handle invalid uri - 404 Error

Tags: rest, error-handling

I want to send a Status response XML from my RESTful web service in case it does not match any valid url. By default it sends a 404 response back to client. Is there any way this can be achieved?

I am using Jersey for implementing RESTful web service.

Comment: The 404 page is normally set at the web server level (Tomcat, IIS...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey has the capability to implement generic exception handler controllers. Basically, controllers which are executed if specific runtime exceptions are not caught otherwise.

The following controller handles exceptions where Jersey could not find another controller.

```
package com.example.controllers;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException;

@Provider
public class NotFoundExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException ex) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
}
```

As an aside, it's usually a good idea to handle any runtime exception in this same manner. Example as follows.

```
package com.example.controllers;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class GenericExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```